# Using an array data item length as part of string in a vue computed property

Tags: vuejs2

I have a data item

```
items: [],
```

which i am using in a computed property that returns the lengh of that array as part of a string.

```
itemSummary : function() {
        return this.items.length === 0 ? "No Items" : "`${this.items.length}` items selected"
}
```

Is it possible to do this with string interpolation....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it in your question. I think the code should be:

```
itemSummary() {
    return this.items.length === 0 ? "No Items" : `${this.items.length} items selected`
}
```

With an interpolated string you put everything inside back quotes and interpolate variables or code snippets by wrapping them in ${ ... }.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals